Nicegui table with dropdown values in specific columns
I'm trying to build table with nicegui and load dynamically data in it. I need to have several columns with selectable values (similar to nicegui table with dropdown select, but values are different for each row)
Example:



Product ID
Product model
Color
Emblem




111
model A
select available color, e.g. green, red
select available emblem


112
model B
select available color, e.g. black, blue, white
select available emblem



...
and so on
In this case, we have different set of values for each row and I can't figure out how to achieve this.
Bonus: All selects should have default value as loaded from db, but if I change it using select, then the whole row should be colored with yellow background (for better UX)
My current code (it works, but without dropdowns):
columns = [
   {"name": "product_id", "label": "Product ID", "field": "product_id"},
   {"name": "product_model", "label": "Product model", "field": "product_model"},
   {"name": "color", "label": "Color", "field": "color"},
   {"name": "emblem", "label": "Emblem", "field": "emblem"},
]

rows = [
   {
      "product_id": item.product_id,
      "product_model": item.product_model,
      "color": item.color if item.color else item.available_colors[0],
      "emblem": item.emblem if item.emblem else item.available_emblems[0],
   }
   for item in db_results
]

table = ui.table(columns=columns, rows=rows).classes("w-full")

Update 1:
I've managed to load different values into column with the following trick:
# see changes here in color:
rows = [
   {
      "product_id": item.product_id,
      "product_model": item.product_model,
      "color": item.available_colors,
      "emblem": item.emblem if item.emblem else item.available_emblems[0],
   }
   for item in db_results
]

table = ui.table(columns=columns, rows=rows).classes("w-full")
table.add_slot('body-cell-color', r'''
    <q-td key="name" :props="props">
        <q-select
            v-model="props.row.color[0]"
            :options="props.row.color"
            @update:model-value="() => $parent.$emit('rename', props.row)"
        />
    </q-td>
''')

But when I select any color in dropdown in cell, then all items in that particular dropdown are being replaced with selected value. What's wrong here?
Update 2
Looks like I made it to work moving through Quasar docs and iterative fixing with Chat GPT:
rows = [
   {
      "product_id": item.product_id,
      "product_model": item.product_model,
      "color": item.available_colors,
      "selected_color": item.available_colors[0],
      "emblem": item.available_emblems,
      "selected_emblem": item.available_emblems[0],
   }
   for item in db_results
]

table = ui.table(columns=columns, rows=rows).classes("w-full")
table.add_slot('body-cell-color', r'''
    <q-td key="color" :props="props">
        <q-select
            v-model="props.row.selected_color"
            :options="props.row.color"
            @update:model-value="() => $parent.$emit('rename', props.row)"
        />
    </q-td>
''')
table.add_slot('body-cell-emblem', r'''
    <q-td key="emblem" :props="props">
        <q-select
            v-model="props.row.selected_emblem"
            :options="props.row.emblem"
            @update:model-value="() => $parent.$emit('rename', props.row)"
        />
    </q-td>
''')

So, the only thing left - highlight rows with changed values.
Anyone?
